# PHP Autoloader add Namespace path

Tags: php, namespaces, require-once, autoloader, spl-autoloader

My MVC structure is following:

```
- web
  -- Classes
    --- Loader.php
  -- Core
    --- Controller.php
    --- Model.php
    --- View.php
    --- Bootstrap.php
    --- DB.php
  -- Project
    --- Controllers (folder)
    --- Models (folder)
    --- Views (folder)
```

Now i have namespaces specified to each. For example i have

```
    namespace Classes; //for Loader.php
    namespace Core; //For Controller.php, Model.php etc...
    namespace Project\Controllers; //For Controllers inside Controllers folder etc...
```

My autoloader looks like this:

```
public static function Autoloader2($className) {
    $className = explode('\\', $className);
    $class = array_pop($className);
    $namespace = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    $file = $namespace . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';

   require $file;
}
```

and My main index.php uses

```
    spl_autoload_register( array('Loader', 'Autoloader2') );
    $app = new Core\Bootstrap();
```

when i open localhost/web/
i get the following error:

```
  Warning: require(Core/Project/Controllers/Index.php): failed to open stream: N
```

It seems it prepends Core/ to the requested file. Index.php is inside Project/Controllers and not Core/Project/Controllers. If i try to remove

```
  //namespace Core; from Bootstrap.php i get the following error
  Fatal error: Class 'Core\Bootstrap' not found
```

Please help

Comment: So, when executing new Core\Bootstrap() you get the Index.php require warning? Correct?

Comment: yes it appends Core/ from namespace thats why it does not find it because Index.php is inside Project/Controllers/ and not inside Core/Project/Controllers

Comment: Do you use any "use" statements for your files
 e.g. use Core\Bootstrap; then $app = new Bootstrap();

Comment: i just added use statemnts to all of the mand error messages keep changing meaning i need to fill up all classes with use and see if that works. I think thats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$app = \Core\Bootstrap();`.

The slash before the path is important, without it your namespace paths will be relative to each other.

Comment: did same thing. I added use statements to all of them and now header is showing. I am new to this and didnt know much about "use" statements

Comment: Use statements is bad practice because you bring everything out in global namespace and then risk name collisions. It is also harder for other programmers to debug your code because it can be hard to trace classes etc..

Comment: everything works now except Views. In my Core\View.php i have $header = new Project\Views\index\header(); this shows the header and also gives error saying could not find Project\Views\index\header.php my Loader suppose to change \ to /

Comment: I do use "use" quite a lot, didnt think it was bad practice, I've seen a lot of frameworks using them. It's certainly not as nice as Java or .NET way!